# Tracking when a mobile user crosses a state or country line?

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, gps, w3c

I'm developing an app for iPhone and Android and I need to be able to track when users cross state lines.  I can grab coordinates through W3C standards, but is there a similar method for converting it to an address?

Comment: I've done some basic searches to see what's available, but everything I've seen is more than I need (and therefore more costly one way or another.) All I really need is a database of cords and a method to return the State. Sending a Google maps request for specific address just seems like overkill and wastes bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can use Geocoder to convert latitude, longitude to Address and you can get Country Name through that. Check here http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html